# Peewee alias not working and throwing AttributeError

Tags: python, peewee

I have a `Order` model and `Payment` model. Payment model has a `jsonb` column `data`.

My Query:

```
orders = (
          Order
          .select(Order, Payment.data.alias('payment_data'))
          .join(Payment, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=(Order.payment==Payment.id))
          .iterator()
         )
```

When I am iterating over the above query, and accessing `order.payment_data`, I am getting an `AttributeError`

But if I write the query below, it gives me the `payment_data` key in the dict while iterating over the orders:

```
orders = (
          Order
          .select(Order, Payment.data.alias('payment_data'))
          .join(Payment, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=(Order.payment==Payment.id))
          .dicts()
          .iterator()
         )
```

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong in the first query and how can have access to `order.payment_data`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> When I am iterating over the above query, and accessing order.payment_data, I am getting an AttributeError

The payment data is probably getting attached to the related payment instance. So instead of `order.payment_data` you would look up the value using:

```
order.payment.payment_data
```

If you want all attributes simply patched directly onto the order, use the `objects()` query method, which skips the model/relation graph:

```
orders = (Order
          .select(Order, Payment.data.alias('payment_data'))
          .join(Payment, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=(Order.payment==Payment.id))
          .objects()  # Do not make object-graph
          .iterator())
for order in orders:
    print(order.id, order.payment_data)
```

This is all covered in the docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#selecting-from-multiple-sources

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of having `NULL` fields in joined results. Probably you miss `payment_data` for some records and peewee doesn't handle this situation as expected.

Check if your query results contain `NULL`s in places of `payment_data`. If so you should probably check if `order` has `payment_data` attribute on each iteration.

Here is more detailed explanation on Github: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1756#issuecomment-430399189

Comment: I will have no payment records for some orders thats why I am doing left outer join on Order. I checked in the case where I do have a payment record associated, still I don't see the `payment_data` attribute.

Comment: Try to include `Payment.id` in your query: `.select(Order, Payment.id, Payment.data.alias('payment_data'))`

Comment: Above also doesn't work. What works is this which I ended up doing. Its a solution but I have to select other columns also from `Payment` model.
`orders = (Order.select(Order, Payment).join(Payment, JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=(Order.payment==Payment.id).alias('payment_table')).dicts().iterator())`